# How to map a PostgreSQL view with Panache in Quarkus

Tags: postgresql, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I want to map an entity to an existing PostgreSQL view on my DB. [This article](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-jpa-entity-to-view-or-sql-query-with-hibernate/) explains how to do it with Hibernate and it seems pretty straightforward: add `@Immutable` to the entity and make sure sur `@Table` name match the view name.

So, here is my entity in Panache :

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "test_view")
public class TestView extends PanacheEntityBase {

  @Id
  public Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "other_test_view_id")
  public OtherTestView otherTestView;

}
```

This actually works, and I can get my views data without any problem. But it looks like Panache is ignoring the `@Immutable` annotation, because if I start my Quarkus app with this parameter :

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=update
```

then I get this error :

```
Error executing DDL "alter table if exists test_view add constraint FKs1taqbpciifj90ycsy164ofpw foreign key (other_test_view_id) references other_test_view"
```

Which makes me think Quarkus is actually treating my Entity as any other, and not as a view. If it were treating it as a view, it should not try to alter a table.

Comment: I'm pretty sure adding @Immutable is equally ignored by Hibernate when generating database update scripts. In other words not unique for Quarkus and a general Hibernate limitation for how it generates the update script. Better to open a feature request against Hibernate for this.

Comment: noted, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `@SubSelect` annotation works and the table is ignored by Panache when creating/updating the db schema :

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@SubSelect(select * from test_view)
@Table(name = "test_view")
public class TestView extends PanacheEntityBase {

  @Id
  public Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "other_test_view_id")
  public OtherTestView otherTestView;

}
```